# FirebaseAuth parou de autenticar o usuário

Tags: android, firebase

No aplicativo, antes do usuário entrar, ele precisar logar com email e senha. Caso não tenha ele pode criar uma conta.

O problema aconteceu ontem a noite, os usuários já cadastrados não conseguem logar mais e não dá nenhum erro. Porém se eu criar uma conta nova, nessa tela eu programei que assim que for feito o cadastro já logar no app.

O problema parece ser a tela de login. No meu lopcat aparece isso

```
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( 7zWrS3nX2lW815oOMzwoxyFRbzc2 ).
D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
```

Se eu colocar senha errada ou email errado ele não está mais verificando também, sendo que dias atrás estava funcionando normalmente.

Minha tela de login

```
    public class TeladeLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edt_Email;
    private EditText edt_Senha;
    private TextView txt_CriarConta;
    private Button btn_Logar;
    private ProgressBar progressBarLogin;

    ValidaEmail validaEmail;
    private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
    VerificaInternet verificaInternet;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_telade_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        edt_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_TelaLogin_Email);
        edt_Senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_TelaLogin_Password);
        txt_CriarConta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_CriarUmaConta);
        btn_Logar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_LogarApp);
        progressBarLogin = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);

        verificaInternet = new VerificaInternet(this);
        validaEmail = new ValidaEmail();

        btn_Logar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (edt_Email.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
                        edt_Senha.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(TeladeLoginActivity.this, "Campos não podem ficar vazios",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else if (!validaEmail.validar(edt_Email.getText().toString())){
                    edt_Senha.setError("Verifique o email digitado");

                }else {

                    String emailUsuario = edt_Email.getText().toString().trim();
                    String senhaUsuario = edt_Senha.getText().toString().trim();
                    criarUser(emailUsuario, senhaUsuario);
                }

            }
        });


        txt_CriarConta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cadastrarUsuario = new Intent(TeladeLoginActivity.this, CadastrarContaActivity.class);
                startActivity(cadastrarUsuario);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        autenticacao = AutenticacaoLogin.getFirebaseAuth();
    }

    private void criarUser(String emailUsuario, final String senhaUsuario) {
       // progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        autenticacao.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                emailUsuario, senhaUsuario
        ).addOnCompleteListener(TeladeLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (verificaInternet.existeConexao()){


                }else if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Intent abrirApp = new Intent(TeladeLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(abrirApp);

                } else {
                    progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    String erroExcecao = "";

                    try {
                        throw task.getException();

                    } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                        erroExcecao = "Email inválido";

                    } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {

                        erroExcecao = "Esse e-mail já está em uso no App.";

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        if (senhaUsuario.length() < 6) {
                            edt_Senha.setText("");//Limpa o campo de texto para o usuário digitar uma nova senha mais forte
                            edt_Senha.requestFocus();//Seta o focus no campo de texto
                            Toast.makeText(TeladeLoginActivity.this, "Senha incorreta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        erroExcecao = "Erro ao logar no aplicativo.";
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(TeladeLoginActivity.this, "Erro: " + erroExcecao, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Notei agora que na activity de cadastrar usuário, não tem um teste de verificação se o dispositivo está conectado na internet. Já na tela de Login tem essa verificação. O que fiz foi remover o mesmo e acrescentar no final do último catch.

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Intent abrirApp = new Intent(TeladeLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(abrirApp);

            } else {
                progressBarLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                String erroExcecao = "";

                try {
                    throw task.getException();

                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                    erroExcecao = "Email ou senha inválidos";

                } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {

                    erroExcecao = "Esse e-mail já está em uso no App.";

                } catch (FirebaseAuthEmailException e) {
                    erroExcecao = "Erro na autenticacao do email";

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    if (senhaUsuario.length() < 6) {
                        edt_Senha.setText("");//Limpa o campo de texto para o usuário digitar uma nova senha mais forte
                        edt_Senha.requestFocus();//Seta o focus no campo de texto
                        Toast.makeText(TeladeLoginActivity.this, "Senha incorreta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    erroExcecao = "Erro ao logar no aplicativo. Verifique se está conectado a internet";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(TeladeLoginActivity.this, erroExcecao, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
}
```